# how to convert date from yyyy-MM-dd to dd-MMM-yyyy without using Date function

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde, simpledateformat, date-format

I have "2011-12-05" and I want to convert this to "Monday 05-Dec-2011".
My date conversion code depends on the device timezone. If my timezone is India, then I get date `Monday 05-Dec-2011` and if my timezone is Kingston, Jamaica, I get `Sunday 04-Dec-2011`.

For this reason my application does not display the correct date for different timezones.

Is there any solution to convert date without `Blackberry Date` class or using current Date and Time Zone?

I want to only convert this date to `String`

I am converting this date using below function

```
public static String reformatMonthDate(String source) 
{
    SimpleDateFormat write = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy"); //YYYY-MMM-dd
    Date date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse(source));
    return write.format(date);
}
```

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way. The former variant is compliant with ISO-8601. There's no reason to jumble it up. ;-)

Comment: i dont want to user any Locale and default .. it gives me just coverting date ..

Comment: my app is based on Event according to date .. and i m getting event in different different Date for different country ..event is same  ..

Comment: If it is working fine then why you want another method.....???
Why you waste your time to find new method.??

Comment: please see my above comment .. i had issue when i converting date in for different location

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a specific locale, instead of relying on the system's default.

```
Locale locale = Locale.get(Locale.LOCALE_fr);

// Parse with HttpDateParser
Date date = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse("2002-01-29"));

// Format with a custom format and locale
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy", locale);
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(30);
String s = formatter.format(date, buf, null).toString(); // mar., 29 janv. 2002
```

Comment: Surprisingly, BlackBerry doesn't have SimpleDateFormat.parse().    http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

DateTimePicker gives the current date according to the location or device configuration settings.

Try this code:
You should get your requirement.

```
public class LoadingScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
private String select_Date[]={"Select Date"};
private String month_ar[]={"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
private ObjectChoiceField choiceField;
private ButtonField show;
public LoadingScreen() 
{
    createGUI();
}
private void createGUI()
{
    choiceField=new ObjectChoiceField("Select Date: ", select_Date, 0)
    {
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
        {
            DateTimePicker datePicker = DateTimePicker.createInstance( Calendar.getInstance(), "dd/MM/yyyy",null);
            datePicker.doModal();
            Calendar cal1=datePicker.getDateTime();
            String day="";
            String mon="";
            if(String.valueOf(cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).length()==1)
            {
                 day="0"+String.valueOf(cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            }
            else
            {
                 day=String.valueOf(cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            }
            mon=String.valueOf(cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            String month=""+month_ar[cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH)];
            select_Date[0]=day+"-"+month+"-"+cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            choiceField.setChoices(select_Date);
            return true;
        }
    };
    add(choiceField);
    show=new ButtonField("Show",FIELD_HCENTER);
    show.setChangeListener(this);
    add(show);
}
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
{
    if(field==show)
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                Dialog.alert(select_Date[choiceField.getSelectedIndex()]);
            }
        });
    }
}
public boolean onMenu(int instance) 
{
    return true;
}
protected boolean onSavePrompt() 
{
    return true;
}
}
```

[image: OutPut]